# how to sum matrix entities as indexing by another vector values?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, sum

Suppose I have a vector `B=[1 1 2 2]` and `A=[5 6 7 4]` in the form of B says the numbers in the A that are need to be summed up. That is we need to sum 5 and 6 as the first entry of the result array and sum 7 and 4 as the second entry. If B is `[1 2 1 2]` then first element of the result is 5+7 and second element is 6+4.

How could I do it in Matlab in generic sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fexible and general approach would be to use [`accumarray()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).

`accumarray(B',A')`

The function accumulates the values in A into the positions specified by B.

Since the documentation is not simple to understand I will summarize why it is flexible. You can:

- choose your **accumulating function** (`sum` by default)
- specify the positions as a set of coordinates for accumulation into **ND arrays**
- **preset the dimension** of the accumulated array (by default it expands to max position)
- **pad** with custom values the non accumulated positions  (pads with `0` by default)
- set the accumulated array to `sparse`, thus potential avoiding **out of memory**

Comment: What an obscure function. Beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

```
[sum(A(1:2:end));sum(A(2:2:end))]
```

Comment: this doesn't work in a general case, when B is some arbitrary input of array indices.

Comment: `accumarray()` is generally fast, but at times, exploiting regularities with simple indexing or reshaping proves to be optimal.